# Using available bytes in Linux Kernel's struct page

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-kernel

I am looking at the definition of `struct page` in the file [`linux/mm_types.h`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/mm_types.h). My question is in regards to the comment at the top of the definition:

```
struct page {
    unsigned long flags;        /* Atomic flags, some possibly
                                 * updated asynchronously */
    /*
     * Five words (20/40 bytes) are available in this union.
     * WARNING: bit 0 of the first word is used for PageTail(). That
     * means the other users of this union MUST NOT use the bit to
     * avoid collision and false-positive PageTail().
     */
```

If I want to use these 20 bytes to store metadata about a page, how would I do so? Is there anything that I would need to check before overwriting those addresses, so that I don't corrupt any valid data that was supposed to be there?